# Remove temporary room sqlite files?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I have a database in my android app, but every time I try to update it (write to it) there are created two additional files `shm` and `wal`. The `wal` file specially is getting bigger and bigger even if I insert the same data to database and it's also bothering me when I try to get the last modified time, the data is written only to `wal` file and not the actual database.

My question is how can I force it to write the data to the database and remove the temp files after each update?

Answer (score 4):

> My question is how can I force it to write the data to the database
>   and remove the temp files after each update?

Yes you can force/initiate a checkpoint.

Closing the database/connection should checkpoint it, but may be costly resource-wise (as you have to re-open it).

Alternately you can use :-

```
PRAGMA wal_checkpoint(TRUNCATE)
```

However, you should consider using

```
PRAGMA wal_checkpoint
```

Before and after the truncate to see if the WAL is busy/ the checkpoint did all (you may wish to amend the example below to check the values wal_busy etc if you adopt it (the example is from a db backup and the database has been closed anyway)).

> The wal_checkpoint pragma returns a single row with three integer columns. The first column is usually 0 but will be 1 if a RESTART or FULL or TRUNCATE checkpoint was blocked from completing

I'd suggest reading [Write-Ahead Logging](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) and [PRAGMA Statements - PRAGMA schema.wal_checkpoint;](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_wal_checkpoint)

> when I try to get the last modified time, the data is written only to
>   wal file and not the actual database.

The -wal file is treated as if it is the database and is read/updated as if it were and thus any changes are extracted from the -wal file if they are in the -wal file. SQLite is pretty safe/sturdy.

## Example

The following is an example of checkpointing :-

```
public static int checkpointDB(SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {

    String TAG = "CHECKPOINTDB";
    int wal_busy = 99, wal_log = 99, wal_checkpointed =99;

    Cursor csr = db.query("PRAGMA journal_mode", null);
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        String mode = csr.getString(0);
        Log.d(TAG, "Mode is " + mode);
        if (mode.toLowerCase().equals("wal")) {
            csr = db.query("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint", null);
            if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
                wal_busy = csr.getInt(0);
                wal_log = csr.getInt(1);
                wal_checkpointed = csr.getInt(2);
            }
            Log.d(TAG,"Checkpoint pre checkpointing Busy = " + String.valueOf(wal_busy) + " LOG = " + String.valueOf(wal_log) + " CHECKPOINTED = " + String.valueOf(wal_checkpointed) );
            csr = db.query("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint(TRUNCATE)", null);
            csr.getCount();
            csr = db.query("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint", null);
            if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
                wal_busy = csr.getInt(0);
                wal_log = csr.getInt(1);
                wal_checkpointed = csr.getInt(2);
            }
            Log.d(TAG,"Checkpoint post checkpointing Busy = " + String.valueOf(wal_busy) + " LOG = " + String.valueOf(wal_log) + " CHECKPOINTED = " + String.valueOf(wal_checkpointed) );
        }
    }
    csr.close();
    return wal_busy;
}
```

It can be called, (where **mPDB** is the built **PersonDatabase** object and the above is in the **PersonDatabase** (@Database) class), using something like :-

```
PersonDatabase.checkpointDB(mPDB.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase());
```

An example usage results in :-

```
2019-07-13 08:15:54.997 18556-18556/s.e.s56720641roomwithmanytomany D/CHECKPOINTDB: Mode is wal
2019-07-13 08:15:54.997 18556-18556/s.e.s56720641roomwithmanytomany D/CHECKPOINTDB: Checkpoint pre checkpointing Busy = 0 LOG = 0 CHECKPOINTED = 0
2019-07-13 08:15:55.000 18556-18556/s.e.s56720641roomwithmanytomany D/CHECKPOINTDB: Checkpoint post checkpointing Busy = 0 LOG = 0 CHECKPOINTED = 0
```

Resulting in :-

[image]

Comment: Is there an alternative way to do it completely via room itself?

Comment: @MaskedMan only by closing the database, it's not what would be classed as typical oo manipulation it's more system management that is outside of the typical standard sqlite installation.

Comment: don't forget to call `csr.close()` before each reassignment.

Answer (score 1):

The presence of those two files means your SQLite DB is operating in [WAL mode](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html), the mechanism is documented extensively.
This is a persistent mode, that can be achieved by running this statement once:

`PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;`

See section '3.3. Persistence of WAL mode' from the link above.
Another useful resource for more in-depth explanations: [Temporary Files Used By SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html)

If this behavior bothers you, you could simply issue the following statement:

`PRAGMA journal_mode=DELETE;`

or `setJournalMode(JournalMode.TRUNCATE)`
as described in the [Android Room docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.JournalMode).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the guided direction. happy coding :)
But  is  there a way to just flush the `wal` to database without setting the journal-mode?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Kotlin version of [MikeT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57014322/444761):

```
fun SupportSQLiteDatabase.performCheckpoint(): Boolean {
    val mode = query("PRAGMA journal_mode").use { cursor ->
        if (!cursor.moveToNext()) {
            return false // not sure if this can happen
        }
        cursor.getString(0)
    }
    println("mode: $mode")
    if (mode.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT) != "wal") {
        return false
    }
    executePragmaThenLog("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint")
    executePragmaThenLog("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint(TRUNCATE)")
    executePragmaThenLog("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint")
    return true
}

private fun SupportSQLiteDatabase.executePragmaThenLog(sql: String) {
    query(sql).use { cursor ->
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            val busy = cursor.getInt(0)
            val log = cursor.getInt(1)
            val cp = cursor.getInt(2)
            val label = sql.removePrefix("PRAGMA ")
            println("$label: busy=$busy, log=$log, checkpointed=$cp")
        }
    }
}
```

Note: you can alternatively use `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor)` to save some code.

Comment: Is there any point in doing the final wal_checkpoint call?  It always seems to give same values as the preceding wal_checkpoint(TRUNCATE)